# TestNG testsuite not running from command line

Tags: command-line, testng, test-suite

I need some help running my testng testsuite from command line:

*Project Structure*

**compiled classes**

```
myproject\bin
myproject\bin\com\...
```

**source classes**

```
myproject\test
myproject\test\com\...
```

**required libraries**

```
myproject\libraries
myproject\libraries\xy.jar
```

**test suite**

```
myproject\test\com\...\test\mySuite.xml
```

**command line call**

```
cd myproject
java -cp libraries\* -Dtestng.test.classpath="bin\*;test\*" org.testng.TestNG test\com\...\test\mySuite.xml
```

**result**

```
[TestNG] Running:
  F:\...\myproject\test\com\...\test\mySuite.xml

===============================================
mySuite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

*UPDATE*

**mySuite.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="mySuite.xml" parallel="classes" thread-count="10">

    <test name="happy path">
        <packages>
            <package name="com...test.functional.happyPath" />
        </packages>
    </test>

    <test name="exception path">  
        <packages>
            <package name="com...test.functional.exceptionPath" />
        </packages>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: Testng need compiled test classes. Is it what your test directory contains?

Comment: Nope. The bin directory contains the compiled classes. But stepping into bin and calling "java -cp ..\libraries\* org.testng.TestNG com\...\test\mySuite.xml" ends in the same result...

Comment: Yes, but where are your compiled test classes? In the bin folder too?

Comment: The project does only contain test classes. So the compiled tests/test-classes all placed in the bin folder.

Comment: I read the following: "https://github.com/longhua/testng-test-classpath-property-issue-1" and then changed my command line call to "java -cp libraries\*;bin org.testng.TestNG test\com\...\test\mySuite.xml". THAT WORKED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the following: http://github.com/longhua/testng-test-classpath-property-issue-1

After that I changed my command line call to:

```
java -cp libraries*;bin org.testng.TestNG test\com\...\test\mySuite.xml
```

That worked for me...